# setContentView and AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have my Android `MainActivity` with its `setContentView`. The view is a black/blue gradient background and an `ImageView`. This is my `onCreate`:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /**
        * Activity elements
        * */
        ImageView rt_logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rt_logo);

        /**
        * Activity variables
        * */
        HttpGetRequest httpGetRequest = new HttpGetRequest(rt_logo);

        try {
        URI uri = new URI("http://www.myurl.com");
        URI[] uris = {uri};

        response = httpGetRequest.execute(uris).get();
    [...]   
    }
```

To retrieve the code of the page, I do an `AsyncTask`. For debug, I use a sleep for 5 seconds.

```
ImageView rt_logo;

public HttpGetRequest(ImageView _rt_logo) {
    rt_logo = _rt_logo;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(URI... uris) {

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uris[0]);


[...]

SystemClock.sleep(5000);
getString = stringBuffer.toString();

return getString;
}
```

My problem is that I get a white screen for 5 seconds before the black/blue gradient and the logo show, I guess after the `AsyncTask`.

Why can't I get it when the app launch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Siddharth I am also a bit confused with what you are trying to do. What you are doing is not entirely wrong, which is basically to start the thread, wait 5 seconds, and then get the info from your Http request. That should not be causing the background from not appearing. But I do have a suspicion; this line:

```
response = httpGetRequest.execute(uris).get();
```

You are expecting a result. Since its a separate thread, odds are you won't have the response you think. Actually it may even be null (I wouldn't know until I see all the code). Anyways I would check that because if you are doing something that may be causing that delay with the response. It would be nice to see what the rest of `onCreate` does.

Comment: It seems to be the right solution.

With httpGetRequest.execute(uris); there is no more problem.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what exactly you are trying to do with your sleep(). But since you have mentioned it in the doInBackground method of your 'AsyncTask' it would be executed only after the Async task has started. If you want to have a delay while you start your app, you should probably code a delay in the onCreate() method outside of the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to execute AsyncTask onCreate() and still have my content.

As Andy says, MainActivity must not expect value from AsyncTask or it will wait before showing  content. So in onCreate, give your activity in argument to AsyncTask and execute it.

```
HttpGetRequest httpGetRequest = new HttpGetRequest(MainActivity.this);

    try {
        URI uri = new URI("http://www.domain.com/live.html");
        URI[] uris = {uri};

        httpGetRequest.execute(uris);

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Wrong URI syntax : " + e.getMessage()); 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then, in your AsyncTask, create an onPostExecute method. In it, finish MainActivity and call another one. If you want it to be invisible by users, disable animation on activity start.

```
Activity activity;

public HttpGetRequest(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public void onPostExecute(String response) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("response", response);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this.activity, LiveActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);

    this.activity.startActivity(intent);

}
```

Send AsyncTask response to your new activity and that's it !